# I am a beginner in Django and facing a syntax error in urls.py

Tags: django, python-3.x, web, django-templates, django-views

Here is my personal/urls.py. I have been trying to solve this for quite a few days. I know it must be a really silly error but help would be appreciated.

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$',views.index, name='index'),
   url(r'contact/',views.contact, name='contact')
   url(r'about/',views.about, name='about')
]
```

And here is the `views.py`

```
def index(request):
  return render(request, 'personal/home.html')

def contact(request):
  return render(request, 'personal/basic.html', {'content':['https://www.facebook.com/arjunkashyap30']})

def about(request):
  return render(request, 'personal/about.html', {'content': ["This is an abut 
page"]})
```

Comment: you missed a comma in 5th line ( contact url )

Answer (score 3):

You forgot `comma` at the end of each endpoint defined.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'contact/',views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'about/',views.about, name='about'),
]
```

Comment: Dammit I knew it was the silliest error. Thanks a thousand times man...